# Jquery Tooltip plugin, don't repeat div append?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml

Ok, I can't see to get this.

I'm making a tooltip plugin that can be applied to multiple items.

I have multiple anchors on a page when mousedover they act as tooltips.  I use the variable c_ttip to act as an identifier for the div because I don't want to set an ID on it.

I want to keep from appending the tooltip and applying the class and css over and over if the same anchor is remoused over before the tooltip mouseout activates the timeout that removes it.

script dev page, http://kalluna.com/_dev-js.do

```
var c_ttip = $('<div>');

return this.each(function() {

 $(this).mouseover(function() {
    c_ttip.appendTo(document.body).hide();
    c_ttip.html('inside my tooltip').addClass('c_ttip_box').css({'top' : obj.position().top + 20, 'left' : obj.position().left}).show();

 }).mouseout(function() {

      timer = setTimeout(function() {
      c_ttip.fadeOut(200, function() { c_ttip.remove();});

    }, 2000);

   });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the object that triggered the tooltip and verify that the object is different before adding the div. Something like:

```
var c_ttip = $('<div>');
var currobject;
...
$(this).mouseover(function() {
if(this == currobject) return;
currobject = this;
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need some form of mutex/flag/semaphore to indicate that you are currently in a timeout/fade situation and that the `mouseover()` event should not fire.

The timer variable you created for the timeout ID could be used for this purpose.  Create it above as a variable (initially `false`), like you have for `c_ttip`.  Then set it to `false` in the `fadeOut()` callback.  The `mouseover()` routine should check to see if `timer != false` when it starts, and exit straight away if it is.

Alternatively, you can add a class to the tooltip when the timer is active, and remove it when the fade has completed.